# Why does the applied function not work on all rows in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following code to get the first part of the string, but however, it does not seem to work. Could someone explain to me **why** it does not work and how I can fix it.

```
library(data.table)
demo <- data.table(ID = c("1234-123", "1521-111", "1214-113", "1412-912"))
demo[, new := lapply(.SD, function(x){
  strsplit(x, "-")[[1]][1]
}), .SDcols = "ID"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` to remove the substring that starts with `-` and any other characters (`.*`) in the 'ID' and assign (`:=`) it to 'new'

```
demo[, new := sub("-.*", "", ID)] 
demo
#        ID  new
#1: 1234-123 1234
#2: 1521-111 1521
#3: 1214-113 1214
#4: 1412-912 1412
```

---

Regarding why the OP' function didn't work, if we check how the `strsplit` `list` elements are extracted (`[[1]]`), it becomes clear.  Here, we extract only the first list element.  As there is only column 'ID', we don't need `.SD`

```
demo[, new := unlist(lapply(strsplit(ID, "-") , `[`, 1))]
```

In the above code, we split the 'ID' by `-`, loop through the `list` elements with `lapply/sapply` and extract the first element to assign it to 'new'.  In case of `lapply`, it is still a `list`, so we `unlist` before assigning